# Setting up Hudson on ec2 and configuring with web gui

Tags: amazon-ec2, hudson, continuous-integration, build-server

I would like to setup hudson on a ec2 micro linux instance. My question is exactly how to configure hudson after i install it remotely via ssh on the ec2 instance. I would like to configure using the hudson web gui. When I have done this locally, this was available at http://localhost:8080/hudson. what about through ec2? and what about security?

Answer (score 1):

It will be available at the external IP address of the EC2 instance, which you can find for example in the AWS web interface. You might also have to configure a security group to allow access to port 8080 and add that instance to that security group.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup an SSH tunnel to route a local port to 8080 on the remote side. I'm afraid I don't use Linux at home enough to explain the process there, but via PuTTY:

1. Choose the connection
2. On the left, go to connections -> SSH -> tunnels
3. Tick "local ports accept connections from other hosts" and "remote ports do the same"
4. Add source port 8080 and remote port 127.0.0.1:8080
5. Connect via SSH, then open http://localhost:8080